# How may I debug the Heroku down cause?

Tags: heroku

I want to know exactly at which point or call my app went down.
This call may be an API call or some event but I want to know so I can debug that point.

Comment: So put a statement into a log file as every single event or call or whatever is called and then completed. The last entry should then give you a clue.

Comment: Looking at [your logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs) would be a good start.